# Update map filtering with html form value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Alright, I don't really know where the issue in my code lies, but maybe it will be obvious to some of you.
I have an html form that includes names of all US states that correspond to numerical values in a geoJSON of all US counties. I use jquery function to get the user selected value, and JS to filter by state and only add those counties to my choropleth map.

```
// get value from form
var value;
$('select').on('click', function() {
    value = this.value;
    return value;
})
//filter by state value
var filtered = L.geoJson(counties, {
    filter: function (features, layer) {
        return features.properties.STATE == value
    }
});
```

I then assign those counties a color based on the Count field (which is default gray) from the geoJSON and have listeners that highlight the county and update an info div on mouseover.

```
// create gradient 
function getColor(d) {
    return d > 1000 ? '#800026' :
        d > 500 ? '#BD0026' :
        d > 200 ? '#E31A1C' :
        d > 100 ? '#FC4E2A' :
        d > 50 ? '#FD8D3C' :
        d > 20 ? '#FEB24C' :
        d > 10 ? '#FED976' :

        '#FFEDA0';
}
// determine fill
function style(feature) {
   if (feature.properties.Count >= 1 && feature.properties.STATE == value) { 
        return {
            fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Count),
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'white',
            dashArray: '3',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        };
     } else if (feature.properties.value != value && feature.properties.Count >= 1) {
        return {
            fillColor: '#DDD',
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'white',
            dashArray: '3',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        }
    } else {
        return {
            fillColor: '#DDD',
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'white',
            dashArray: '3',
            fillOpacity: 0.7

        }
    }

}

function highlightFeature(e) {
    var layer = e.target;

    layer.setStyle({
        weight: 5,
        color: '#666',
        dashArray: '',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    });

    if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
        layer.bringToFront();
    }
    info.update(layer.feature.properties);
}

function resetHighlight(e) {
    geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
    info.update();
}
var geojson;
// listeners
geojson = filtered;

function zoomToFeature(e) {
    map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
}

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight,
        click: zoomToFeature
    });
}

geojson = L.geoJson(counties, {
    style: style,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(mymap);
var info = L.control();

info.onAdd = function (mymap) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); // create info div
    this.update();
    return this._div;
};

// update info on hover
info.update = function (props) {
    
    this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>2020 Sales</h4>' + (props ?
    props.NAME + ' county: '
           + props.Count + ' sales / county' :
        'Hover over a state/county');
};



info.addTo(mymap);
</script>
```

My problem is it only updates the filtered county fill color on mouseover of the county when a state is selected from the form, whereas I want to update the entirety of the filtered county's fill color on the state select. I have a bit more code I can include on request (css and some map setup js), but I think included the pertinent stuff.
Also, this is based on the leaflet choropleth example.

EDIT
Here is the google drive link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YMQZWgQb1UJga0SnXkYT50067KSz5il3?usp=sharing , let me know if there is an issue.
The code is too large to host live. Select a state from the list on the bottom left of the page, e.i. California, and you will see my problem

Comment: You're obviously using a another library you wasn't mention, what is it? Also, although this library doesn't look familiar to me I might could help but I'll need to see it in action so I could debug it. Therefor a working codepan or something is welcome :)

Comment: I've edited to add a link